# backcolor is not a member of system.web.ui.control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, backcolor

I am creating some controls in a table runtime and adding them to List(Of T) for using them in future. Now I want to change the backcolor of the table's column which contains ImageList(x). Here ImageList() is a list of Images. But when I try to change the backcolor of the table's column i.e. parent of imagelist(x) it says backcolor is not a member of system.web.ui.control.

Here is the code

```
For x As Integer = 0 To FileImageList.Count - 1
            If sender.id.substring(3) = FileImageList(x).ID.Substring(3) Then
                FileNameList(x).Parent.backcolor = Drawing.Color.Green
            End If
        Next
```

What might be the problem? Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the type of Imagelist() to Object and it works fine. No errors.